# Git2go - go get command returns "Not defined link to 'git_blob_create_fromchunks'"

Tags: go, get, libgit2

When I install git2go with

> go get github.com/libgit2/git2go

Then I get following error:

> /tmp/go-build323687976/github.com/libgit2/git2go/_obj/wrapper.o: In
>   Funktion _go_git_blob_create_fromchunks':
>   ../../../libgit2/git2go/wrapper.c:121: Nicht definierter Verweis
>   aufgit_blob_create_fromchunks'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

"Nicht definierter Verweis auf" means "Not defined link to"

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to install the version of git2go that matches your installed version of libgit2.

Comment: That was it, actually ... Do want to put that as an answer?